# Retrieving and setting dynamically loaded image sizes via js

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svelte

Consider this javascript code:

```
const profileImageURL = 'https://api.images.com/image/' + id +'/profile';
let profileImage = [];

async function getProfileImage() {
    const response = await fetch(profileImageURL);
    profileImage = await response.json();
};
```

and this svelte template code:

```
<div class="thumbImg">
    {#await getProfileImage()}
    <div class='spinnerHolder'
        in:fade={{duration: 500}} 
        out:fade={{duration: 500}} 
        on:introstart={() => doneLoading = false} 
        on:outroend={() => doneLoading = true}
        >
        <svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
    {:then value}
        {#if doneLoading}
            <img transition:fade alt='profile-image' src={profileImage.url}/>
        {/if}
    {/await}
</div>
```

and css:

```
.thumbImg {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: var(--border-color);
    border: none;
    border-radius: var(--large-radius);
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
        min-width: 64px;
        border-radius: var(--large-radius);
        border-image-width: 0;
    }
}
```

The above loaded images arrive at different widths and heights. Some portrait and some landscape. They need to all be displayed in a square 1:1 box that is 64px x 64px without white space at the side or the bottom. How can I maintain the aspect ratio of these dynamically loaded images so that they either fill the width or height depending on which is needed ? Ideally they would also be offset so they are centered in the 1:1 box.

Visual Examples of the problem:

[image]
[image]

Comment: try doing this for the class `.thumbImg` or `img` tag - `max-width: 64px` and `max-height: 64px`

Comment: ja.. i've tried this and it doesn't work. If the image is portrait then you get white space at the side :(

Comment: have you tried doing absolute positioning of the `img` tag?

Comment: how do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Now I finally understood the problem when I saw the picture. Try to put - `min-width: 100%`.

Comment: this also doesn't work, thanks though! :D

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer building on Rich's comment below**

You can use the [object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) and [object-position](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position/) CSS properties together to fine tune the way the image is displayed inside its content box:

```css
.thumbImg {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: var(--border-color);
    border: none;
    border-radius: var(--large-radius);
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
        height: 64px;
        width: 64px;
        object-fit: cover; // this will make the image cover the content box, clipping horizontally if the original image is landscape orientation, or vertically if it is portrait orientation
        object-position: 50% 50%; // this will center the image in the content box (i.e. clip on the left & right if source is landscape and clip top & bottom if source is portrait)
    }
}
```

With this, you do not need to modify your code any further.

**Original answer, using CSS background images**

You can achieve the desired positioning by using background image CSS properties rather than an `img` tag, for example:

```css
.avatar {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    background-size: cover; // this will make the image cover the div, clipping horizontally if the original image is landscape orientation, or vertically if it is portrait orientation
    background-position: 50% 50%; // this will center the image (i.e. clip on the left & right if source is landscape and clip top & bottom if source is portrait)
}
```

With this, all you have to do is replace your `<img>` tag with a `<div class="avatar">` tag and set the background image source dynamically:

```js
<div class="thumbImg">
    {#await getProfileImage()}
    <div class='spinnerHolder'
        in:fade={{duration: 500}} 
        out:fade={{duration: 500}} 
        on:introstart={() => doneLoading = false} 
        on:outroend={() => doneLoading = true}
        >
        <svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
    {:then value}
        {#if doneLoading}
            <div
                transition:fade
                class="avatar"
                alt="Profile image"
                style="background-image: url('{profileImage.url}')"
            />
        {/if}
    {/await}
</div>
```

Of course the downside is that you're not using a native image tag anymore, and maybe this is important to you. On the upside, it works without having to use javascript-based DOM manipulation.

Comment: amazing! this is exactly what i needed!!

Comment: You don't need to use a background, you can use a combination of [object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) and [object-position](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position/) on a regular `<img>`

Comment: Answer updated, thank you @RichHarris. I was not aware of these properties, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the images width and height relative to the parent div by using percentage values or just set the images to the required max-width and max-height

```
.thumbImg {
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: var(--border-color);
    border: none;
    border-radius: var(--large-radius);
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
        max-width: 100%; //relative to the parent DIV
        border-radius: var(--large-radius);
        border-image-width: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: hiya.. thanks for this, but this still doesn't work :(

Comment: i imagine the answer is probably going to use JS :D

Comment: @TimmyLee Just one last idea. Did you use a min-width of 100% to the img selector?